# Can I make this Phone Validator Regex more efficient?

Tags: java, regex

I started a few days ago to mess with Regex and today I was requested to make a fast regex. (Is it really an art to create efficient regexes?)

So I wrote this simple Regex to match an Israeli Phone Number:
`^05[23489]-?[\d]{3}-?[\d]{4}$`
But will it do the job which is to complete verifying around 10,000 phone numbers within 1 or 2 seconds? I don't have a computer here so I can't check.
Thanks for any improvement!

The match rules are:

- Starts with 05, then one of: 0, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9
- then Optional Hyphen
- then 3 digits
- then Optional '-'
- Ultimately come 4 digits.

A few examples to **Valid** phone numbers:

1. 052-587-6549
2. 0531432941
3. 058-3219321
4. 059-321-1353

Comment: *But is it really enough to verify around 10,000 phone numbers in 1 or 2 seconds?*: have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Can you give a few valid and invalid phone numbers for us to use to test the speed?

Comment: oh I forgot to meantion that I don't have a computer right now and that mission is urgent.. no I haven't tried.

Comment: Ah, so you're writing this message on... a typewriter? Here's an online IDE you can use, even on your phone. https://ideone.com/

Comment: lol no I'm from my phone o.O thanks for the site, I'll check random phone numbers and update the post correspondingly to the result.

Comment: Hilarious, isn't it, to think someone still uses typewriters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[23489]` does not include `0`. Besides, it is not a good idea to wrap single `\d` with character class brackets, `[\d]` = `\d`.

Use

```
^05[023489]-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$
    ^
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mnJwc6/1).

In Java, you do not need `^` and `$` anchors if you use the pattern with `.matches()`  method as itrequires a full string match.

```
if (phone.matches("05[023489]-?\\d{3}-?\\d{4}")) {
    // This is valid
}
```